# Installation using pip in virtualenv on CentOS encounters segmentation fault

Tags: python, linux, django, pip

I have a Linux CentOS 6.7 installation on a VM. A few months ago, I had
- compiled and installed Python 2.7.8 on it
- installed virtualenv-13.1.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
- installed Django 1.7 inside the virtualenv.
- compiled and installed mod_wsgi 4.4.21 and used it to deploy Django on Apache

I have been using this over the last few months with no issues.

I am now trying to upgrade to Django 1.8.8. I activated the virtualenv and then executed the following command, but it encounters a segmentation fault each time.

```
$pip2.7 install --upgrade django==1.8.8

Collecting django==1.8.8

/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
Downloading Django-1.8.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
99% |############################### | 6.2MB 9.1MB/s eta 0:00:01Segmentation fault
```

If I preface the command with sudo, there is no segmentation fault, but it does not proceed to install the new version of Django at all.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Edit:

Output of verbose output given below
    pip2.7 install --upgrade django==1.8.8 -v

```
Collecting django==1.8.8
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
"GET /simple/django/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3985
1 location(s) to search for versions of django:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
"GET /simple/django/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3985
Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Django/Django-1.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=07f0d2d42162945d0ad031fc9737847d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Django/Django-1.5.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=1e3418bd1d6f9725a3d1264c9352f2a1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.5.8
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Django/Django-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=c7b7a4437b36400f1c23953e9700fd29 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Django/Django-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=3bd014923e85df771b34d12c0ab3c9e1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/any/D/Django/Django-1.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=2bcdb4729f9f358b0925b532eef0a8ff (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.6.5
..................................
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.8.8.tar.gz#md5=08ecf83b7e9d064ed7e3981ddc3a8a15 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.8.8
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.8.9.tar.gz#md5=49f6863b1c83825fb2f473c141c28e15 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.8.9
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.8.tar.gz#md5=9a811faf67ca0f3e0d43e670a1cc503d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.8
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.9.1.tar.gz#md5=02754aa2d5c9c171dfc3f9422b20e12c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.9.1
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.9.2.tar.gz#md5=ee90280973d435a1a6aa01b453b50cd1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.9.2
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.9.tar.gz#md5=110389cf89196334182295165852e082 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.9
Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.9rc1.tar.gz#md5=b971686521ea09b4bf82aec3e794fcbc (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/), version: 1.9rc1
Using version 1.8.8 (newest of versions: 1.8.8, 1.8.8)
"GET /packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.8.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl HTTP/1.1" 200 6170205
Downloading Django-1.8.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.8.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=97334c82efbac0f93f8b6dd4ee4b516f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/)
99% |############################### | 6.2MB 4.8MB/s eta 0:00:01Segmentation fault
```

I get the same result if I try to upgrade to version 1.7.11 (tried that to see if there is any incompatibility between Python 2.7.8 and Django 1.8.x).

I also get the same result if I try to install any other package. So it is not a Django-specific problem, maybe it is related to pip and virtualenv ?

I've now created a new virtualenv called syt_env, activated it and tried to install Django afresh. Hitting a different error now. Note that it seems to be still trying to install in the old virtualenv called vishwaas_env.

```
Collecting Django==1.8.8 (from -r requirements/base.txt (line 1))
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 305, in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 705, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 461, in _prepare_file
req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 250, in populate_link
self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 486, in find_requirement
all_versions = self._find_all_versions(req.name)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 404, in _find_all_versions
index_locations = self._get_index_urls_locations(project_name)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 378, in _get_index_urls_locations
page = self._get_page(main_index_url)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 818, in _get_page
return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 928, in get_page
"Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 373, in request
return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 36, in send
cached_response = self.controller.cached_request(request)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 102, in cached_request
resp = self.serializer.loads(request, self.cache.get(cache_url))
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 108, in loads
return getattr(self, "_loads_v{0}".format(ver))(request, data)
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 170, in _loads_v2
cached["response"]["body"]
File "/home/syt_admin/.virtualenvs/vishwaas_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 20, in _b64_decode_bytes
return base64.b64decode(b.encode("ascii"))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2662: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: wild guess, as you said you should use sudo but you are not in your virtual environment or you have not activated your virtual environment. So Django1.8 is installed globally and this does not affect your virtualenv

Comment: So how do I use sudo and still install it within the virtual environment?

Comment: I guess First you have to activate virtualenv (. venv/bin/activate) and the pip command without sudo, also try pip freeze command to check packages you have in virtualenv.

Comment: I did activate the virtualenv and executed pip2.7 command inside the virtual environment. The Django 1.8.8 package is downloaded, but hits a segmentation fault immediately after the download completes. If I stay within the virtualenv and execute "sudo pip2.7 install ...." it downloads the package and then does nothing.

Comment: @Tanuka Sorry, you are right, when you install into a virtualenvironment you do not need sudo. Have you tried a different Django version?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'll try a different Django version and see how that goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the error turned to be a known issue with pip version 7.1.2.

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2674

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3245

Used the workaround of invoking pip2.7 with the option --no-cache-dir and was able to install all required packages in the new virtualenv and also upgrade the old packages in the earlier virtualenv.

pip2.7 install --upgrade django==1.8.8  --no-cache-dir

Answer (score 0):

Paste here output:

```
pip2.7 install --upgrade django==1.8.8 -v
```

*-v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.*

Btw there is a newer version of Django [[1.8.9]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8.9/)

Comment: Edited the question to include this output. The segmentation fault occurs with other versions of Django as well.

Comment: try: `pip install -U pip`